# Porque no puedo filtar por fecha, Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Ya intente usando:

```
1.-
    $this->db->where('a.fecha >= "'.$date1.'"');
    $this->db->where('a.fecha <= "'.$date2.'"');
2.-
    $this->db->where('DATE(a.fecha)',$date2);
3.-
$this->db->where('a.fecha',date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date1))); ....
```

Si directamente en mysql pongo:

```
SELECT * FROM `entrada` where fecha >= "2018-07-14" and fecha <= "2018-07-14"
```

me funciona perfectamente, mostrando información.

no entiendo porque no me funciona usando codeigniter de ninguna forma.

Comment: No le pongas comillas a las variables y pon una `,`  entre el criterio y la variable. Prueba así: `$this->db->where('a.fecha >= ',$date1);  $this->db->where('a.fecha <= ',$date2);`

Answer (score 2):

Si revisas la [documentación de Query Builder](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html) verás que hay varios formas de pasar los parámetros:

1. Poniendo los `where` seguidos uno de otro, pero sin intentar tú construir la cadena de criterio. Solamente tienes que pasar la condición (a la izquierda)  y la variable (a la derecha), ambos parámetros separados por coma. Y, claro, debes asegurarte que las variables son fechas válidas, de lo contrario no funcionará:

   ```
   $this->db->where('a.fecha >= ',$date1);
   $this->db->where('a.fecha <= ',$date2);
   ```
2. Puedes pasar los parámetros en un array asociativo donde cada clave sería el criterio y el cada valor el dato que se usará en el criterio:

   ```
   $array = array('a.fecha >=' => $date1, 'a.fecha <=' => $date2);
   $this->db->where($array);
   ```

Comment: Así lo tenia principalmente pero igual no me funciono

Comment: @Even, si no funciona debes revisar entonces tus variables `$date1` y `$date2`, no sea que se estén creando mal o con un formato equivocado como `DD-MM-YYYY` ... supongo que la columna `fecha` de tu tabla es del tipo `DATETIME`

Comment: es date, y el valor valor viene: 0000-00-00 YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: @Even  ¿y ese es el valor correcto?, una fecha `0000-00-00` es una fecha nula. ¿Ese es el valor que hay en las variables?